# How to tunnel localhost on android

Tags: python, android, localhost, webserver, http-tunneling

I have a python webserver which has webhooks , when posted in localhost on desktop and tunnel it through loophole.site it works

I further ran the python webserver code in Android 12 it works on ports > 1024 but my trading view alert webhooks only accepts from http Port:80 or https:443 also localhost address its not accepting

Pls guide me on how to access port:80 without rooting the device like a superuser or tunnel the localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000/webhook in android to enable the webserver working in android ,

the webserver uses Get alerts payload & Push to perform some actions on a exchange

I have attached a few pics for your reference
The apk is pydroid and python version is > 3.7
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsLkz.jpg)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Think that a webhook cannot work if the Android device uses a mobile connection only. As the Android webserver app is unreachable for a client on the internet then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use android emulator use `http://10.0.2.2:[your port]`

Comment: No... Emulator... Server running on mobile browser localhost

Comment: `Server running on mobile browser localhost` A server runs on a device. What does it have to with a browser? And what with localhost? Every device is its own localhost. And why do you talk about mobile? No wifi?

Comment: I actually use AWS cloud, where the script is hosted and it works... But what if the server is hosted in mobile itself it would be more convenient and free anytime that's why trying in mobile